# Android: Creating a horizontal ScrollView with columns of text

Tags: android, layout

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any method for taking a bunch of text and displaying it in a ScrollView that has multiple columns that scroll horizontally.

I'm trying to create an experience very similar to Aldiko or the Kindle app in which the user can tap left or right to go to the previous or next page of text.

Hope this makes sense, thanks for reading,

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aldiko (and Stanza) are using `WebView` + CSS3 columns. You "paginate" this way and then just scroll horizontally. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766797/how-to-break-up-html-documents-into-pages-for-ebook/2815770#2815770).

Comment: Thanks alex! What you suggested is how I ended up implementing it.
A word of caution though, the -webkit-column-width property is not guaranteed unless you also set a width.