# Wrapping text horizontally

Tags: android, layout, string-formatting

I'm doing an app of a book and am trying to work out which layout to use so the text reads like an iPad/kindle where you swipe horizontally to turn the page. I've used HorizontalScrollView, but is there a way to get the layout to wrap the text into a new column that you then scroll onto?
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the font size?

Comment: no, I'm trying to get the text from a @string to wrap when it gets to the end of the line without me having to use \n. I'm v new to java/android I'm pretty sure its a simple thing, but currently the string just extends off the screen.

Comment: When adding the above comment I realised the word I was looking for was "wrap", thus the new title.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are displaying your `String`. I would use a `JTextArea` and turn wrapping on. If you're using a `JLabel`, then I believe you can set the width and wrap the text in a `<html>` tag and it will automatically wrap.

Comment: I think the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269105/android-creating-a-horizontal-scrollview-with-columns-of-text  thanks